# I upgraded Python 2.5 to 2.6 but now get "ImportError: No module named tagging.views"

Tags: python, django

**THE ISSUE**

The problem: it seems like the `tagging` module which I have in my `/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tagging` is not being included because I upgraded the system to 2.6, despite my assumption of relying on 2.5 in virtualenv mode.

Here's the error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=10470): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/workarounds/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 141, in get_response
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 176, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 239, in _get_urlconf_module
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/srv/workarounds/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from tagging.views import tagged_object_list
[Thu Mar 24 00:08:35 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named tagging.views
```

**MY SETUP**

Firstly, here's my setup:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
$ python
>>> import django
django.VERSION
(1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

My django projects live in `/srv`. My virtual envs live in `/srv/python-environments`

If I `cd` into `/srv/` and do:

`source python-environments/saltycrane/bin/activate`

The python version becomes:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.5.2
```

My project, `/srv/workarounds` uses `/srv/workarounds/apache/django.wsgi`, which is composed of:

```
import os, sys, site

virtualenv = '/srv/python-environments/saltycrane/'

ALLDIRS = [os.path.join(virtualenv, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')]

# Remember original sys.path.
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)

# Add project directory
sys.path.append( '/srv/' )
sys.path.append( '/srv/workarounds/' )

for directory in ALLDIRS:
    site.addsitedir( directory )

new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)

sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'workarounds.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The code basically adds `/srv/` and `/srv/workarounds` to the python path when the wsgi is run by Apache.

**SO....**

How can I adjust my wsgi to keep using Python 2.5.2 instead of 2.6? Or if not, how can I update my virtualenv to use python 2.6 packages with `pip`?

**THINGS IM NOT SURE ABOUT**

1. Perhaps it runs on 2.6 and *does* grab the `tagging` module, but the tagging module or a part of it isn't compatible, therefore that's why it complains of `No module named tagging.views` ?
2. Maybe this has nothing to do with 2.5 to 2.6 and was always present? But I doubt this very much because I did several restarts with that code in place, and it worked fine.
3. It could have been a Django subtle version update, I might have updated 1.1 or 1.2beta to 1.2.3 final.

**EDIT**: If I have the right mod_wsgi.so, it's compiled for 2.6.

```
/usr/lib/apache2/modules$ ldd mod_wsgi.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf57fe000)
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0xb760f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb75f6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb75f2000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0xb75ed000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb75c7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7482000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7438000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb72e0000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb72cc000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb788e000)
```

Comment: Before being able to give correct advice, you need to verify what version of Python mod_wsgi is compiled against. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library' to work this out.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton - I did a `sudo find . -name 'mod_wsgi.so` from `/` and fed it to `ldd`. It seems to be compiled for 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you changed this it might work:

`ALLDIRS = [os.path.join(virtualenv, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')]`

to

`ALLDIRS = [os.path.join(virtualenv, 'lib', 'python2.5', 'site-packages')]`

**Setting your WSGIPythonHome is what is suggested when using virtualenv with modwsgi:**

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=python2.5 BASELINE
```

and setup modwsgi to use that as the wsgipythonhome

**[Baseline Environment](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments)**

> The first step in using virtual
>   environments with mod_wsgi is to point
>   mod_wsgi at a baseline Python
>   environment. This step is actually
>   optional and if not done the main
>   Python installation for the system,
>   usually that which mod_wsgi was
>   compiled for, would be used as the
>   baseline environment.
>
> Although the main Python installation
>   can be used, especially in a shared
>   environment where daemon mode of
>   mod_wsgi is used to host WSGI
>   applications for different users, it
>   is better to make the baseline
>   environment a virgin environment with
>   an effectively empty 'site-packages'
>   directory. This way there is no
>   possibility of conflicts between
>   modules and packages in a users
>   individual Python virtual environment
>   and the baseline environment.
>
> To create a virgin environment using
>   the 'virtualenv' program, the
>   '--no-site-packages' option should be
>   supplied when creating the
>   environment.

```
$ cd /usr/local/pythonenv

$ virtualenv --no-site-packages BASELINE
New python executable in BASELINE/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
```

> Note that the version of Python from
>   which this baseline environment is
>   created must be the same version of
>   Python that mod_wsgi was compiled for.
>   It is not possible to mix environments
>   based on different major/minor
>   versions of Python.
>
> Once the baseline Python environment
>   has been created, the WSGIPythonHome
>   directive should be defined within the
>   global part of the main Apache
>   configuration files. The directive
>   should refer to the top level
>   directory for the baseline environment
>   created by the 'virtualenv' script.

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/pythonenv/BASELINE
```

> This Python environment will now be
>   used as the baseline environment for
>   all WSGI applications running under
>   mod_wsgi, whether they be run in
>   embedded mode or daemon mode.
>
> There is no need to set the
>   WSGIPythonHome directive if you want
>   to use the main Python installation as
>   the baseline environment.

Comment: You cannot use WSGIPythonHome to make mod_wsgi use a different major/minor version of Python than what mod_wsgi was specifically compiled against. Nor should you add a site-packages directory from one major/minor version of Python into sys.path when using a different major/minor version of Python. I would therefore be cautious in following this advice. OP needs to determine what version of mod_wsgi is built against and have everything use the same major/minor version. See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library'.

Comment: The advice was an answer to `How can I adjust my wsgi to keep using Python 2.5.2 instead of 2.6?`

Comment: But if his mod_wsgi is compiled against Python 2.6, you cannot use either mechanism to have it use a Python 2.5 virtual environment. Mixing of installed stuff for different versions of Python is dangerous. If he really wants to keep using Python 2.5 and mod_wsgi is using Python 2.6, the only solution is to install mod_wsgi which is compiled against Python 2.5. They need to determine what version mod_wsgi is using before one can give correct advice.

Comment: From the title, I gathered that he had a working mod_wsgi setup compiled for python2.5 and when he upgraded to python2.6 he didn't change his mod_wsgi. I guess I shouldn't be making assumptions.

Comment: Its a bit vague as to what is what. If Python was upgraded to Python 2.6, then was Python 2.5 left in place. If mod_wsgi was compiled against Python 2.5, then it would have had to if mod_wsgi were to still work. If that is the case and both Python 2.5 and 2.6 are present and all that has really happened is the default is now 2.6, then for the command line they could just run 'python2.5' executable. If however mod_wsgi was also updated to use Python 2.6, then it gets more complicated. Thus why important to know the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for both your replies guys - I'm sorry I left out the mod_wsgi info. I have updated and it seems to be compiled for 2.6. I'm fine with using 2.6 and re-downloading all my site-packages again instead of trying to use 2.5, but I need instructions on how I should properly do it.